# Cannot create Android apps in Xamarin Studio

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin-studio

I have searched over and over again but cannot find a solution. I also tried installing on two different machines with the same errors.

I installed from VS 2017 installer and also standalone from monodevelop.com to no avail.

Android app option is disabled in Xamarin Studio and therefore I cannot create a project.

Also tried re-installing everything (including VS with all options to no avail).

SDKs are also set correctly.

Screenshots:

[image]

[image]

Android Tools Log:

```
[2017-07-20 11:16:13.0] INFO: sdk:   Key HKCU\SOFTWARE\Novell\Mono for Android\AndroidSdkDirectory found:
    Path contains adb in \platform-tools (C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk).
[2017-07-20 11:16:13.0] INFO: sdk:   Key HKCU\SOFTWARE\Novell\Mono for Android\AndroidNdkDirectory found:
    Path contains ndk-stack in \. (C:\android-ndk-r15b).
[2017-07-20 11:16:13.0] INFO: sdk:   Key HKCU\SOFTWARE\Novell\Mono for Android\JavaSdkDirectory found:
    Path contains jarsigner.exe in \bin (C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_131).
[2017-07-20 11:16:13.0] INFO: Did not find Xamarin.Android
[2017-07-20 11:16:13.0] INFO: Found Android SDK. API levels: (none)
[2017-07-20 11:19:24.2] INFO: sdk:   Key HKCU\SOFTWARE\Novell\Mono for Android\AndroidSdkDirectory found:
    Path contains adb in \platform-tools (C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk).
[2017-07-20 11:19:24.2] INFO: sdk:   Key HKCU\SOFTWARE\Novell\Mono for Android\AndroidNdkDirectory found:
    Path contains ndk-stack in \. (C:\android-ndk-r15b).
[2017-07-20 11:19:24.2] INFO: sdk:   Key HKCU\SOFTWARE\Novell\Mono for Android\JavaSdkDirectory found:
    Path contains jarsigner.exe in \bin (C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_131).
[2017-07-20 11:19:24.2] INFO: Found Android SDK. API levels: (none)
[2017-07-20 11:19:24.2] INFO: sdk:   Key HKCU\SOFTWARE\Novell\Mono for Android\AndroidSdkDirectory found:
    Path contains adb in \platform-tools (C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk).
[2017-07-20 11:19:24.2] INFO: sdk:   Key HKCU\SOFTWARE\Novell\Mono for Android\AndroidNdkDirectory found:
    Path contains ndk-stack in \. (C:\android-ndk-r15b).
[2017-07-20 11:19:24.2] INFO: sdk:   Key HKCU\SOFTWARE\Novell\Mono for Android\JavaSdkDirectory found:
    Path contains jarsigner.exe in \bin (C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_131).
[2017-07-20 11:19:24.2] INFO: Found Android SDK. API levels: (none)
[2017-07-20 11:19:24.2] INFO: sdk:   Key HKCU\SOFTWARE\Novell\Mono for Android\AndroidSdkDirectory found:
    Path contains adb in \platform-tools (C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk).
[2017-07-20 11:19:24.2] INFO: sdk:   Key HKCU\SOFTWARE\Novell\Mono for Android\AndroidNdkDirectory found:
    Path contains ndk-stack in \. (C:\android-ndk-r15b).
[2017-07-20 11:19:24.2] INFO: sdk:   Key HKCU\SOFTWARE\Novell\Mono for Android\JavaSdkDirectory found:
    Path contains jarsigner.exe in \bin (C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_131).
[2017-07-20 11:19:24.2] INFO: Found Android SDK. API levels: (none)
[2017-07-20 11:19:24.2] INFO: Did not find Xamarin.Android
[2017-07-20 11:19:24.2] INFO: sdk:   Key HKCU\SOFTWARE\Novell\Mono for Android\AndroidSdkDirectory found:
    Path contains adb in \platform-tools (C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk).
[2017-07-20 11:19:24.2] INFO: sdk:   Key HKCU\SOFTWARE\Novell\Mono for Android\AndroidNdkDirectory found:
    Path contains ndk-stack in \. (C:\android-ndk-r15b).
[2017-07-20 11:19:24.2] INFO: sdk:   Key HKCU\SOFTWARE\Novell\Mono for Android\JavaSdkDirectory found:
    Path contains jarsigner.exe in \bin (C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_131).
[2017-07-20 11:19:24.2] INFO: Found Android SDK. API levels: (none)
```

IDE Log:

```
INFO [2017-07-20 11:40:23Z]: Starting Xamarin Studio 6.3 (build 863)
INFO [2017-07-20 11:40:23Z]: Running on Microsoft .NET 4.0.30319.42000
INFO [2017-07-20 11:40:23Z]: Operating System: Windows 10.0.10586.0 (64-bit)
INFO [2017-07-20 11:40:23Z]: Found GTK# version 2.12.38
WARNING [2017-07-20 11:40:24Z]: Storage folder: C:\Users\livob002\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Cache\AppInsights\ad58ff9da41d9e46a009b5b523971c10f8ed4e28
INFO [2017-07-20 11:40:24Z]: Using GTK+ 2.24.26
INFO [2017-07-20 11:40:25Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.Core
INFO [2017-07-20 11:40:25Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.Ide
INFO [2017-07-20 11:40:27Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.WindowsPlatform
INFO [2017-07-20 11:40:27Z]: Initializing Runtime MS.NET
INFO [2017-07-20 11:40:27Z]: GTK: Using Gtk theme from C:\Users\livob002\AppData\Roaming\XamarinStudio-6.0\Config\share\themes\Dark
Starting Xamarin Studio
INFO [2017-07-20 11:40:28Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.Debugger
INFO [2017-07-20 11:40:28Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.SourceEditor2
INFO [2017-07-20 11:40:28Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.TextTemplating
INFO [2017-07-20 11:40:28Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.DesignerSupport
INFO [2017-07-20 11:40:28Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.Xml
INFO [2017-07-20 11:40:28Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.AspNet
INFO [2017-07-20 11:40:28Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.UnitTesting
INFO [2017-07-20 11:40:28Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.RegexToolkit
INFO [2017-07-20 11:40:28Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.Refactoring
INFO [2017-07-20 11:40:28Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.CSharpBinding
INFO [2017-07-20 11:40:28Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.PackageManagement
INFO [2017-07-20 11:40:28Z]: Add-in loaded: Xamarin.Ide.Insights
INFO [2017-07-20 11:40:29Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.Xamarin.Ide
INFO [2017-07-20 11:40:29Z]: Add-in loaded: Xamarin.Ide.Identity
INFO [2017-07-20 11:40:29Z]: Add-in loaded: Xamarin.TestCloud
INFO [2017-07-20 11:40:29Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.Debugger.Soft
INFO [2017-07-20 11:40:29Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.MonoAndroid
INFO [2017-07-20 11:40:29Z]: Add-in loaded: Xamarin.Forms.Addin
INFO [2017-07-20 11:40:29Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.GtkCore
INFO [2017-07-20 11:40:29Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.FSharpBinding
INFO [2017-07-20 11:40:29Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.VBBinding
INFO [2017-07-20 11:40:30Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.VersionControl
INFO [2017-07-20 11:40:30Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.Packaging
   Loading Workbench
INFO [2017-07-20 11:40:30Z]: Add-in loaded: Xamarin.TestCloud.NUnit
INFO [2017-07-20 11:40:30Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.WebReferences
INFO [2017-07-20 11:40:30Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.ConnectedServices
INFO [2017-07-20 11:40:30Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.DocFood
INFO [2017-07-20 11:40:30Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.AssemblyBrowser
INFO [2017-07-20 11:40:30Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.VersionControl.Git
INFO [2017-07-20 11:40:30Z]: ANDROID: sdk:   Key HKCU\SOFTWARE\Novell\Mono for Android\AndroidSdkDirectory found:
    Path contains adb in \platform-tools (C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk).
INFO [2017-07-20 11:40:30Z]: ANDROID: sdk:   Key HKCU\SOFTWARE\Novell\Mono for Android\AndroidNdkDirectory found:
    Path contains ndk-stack in \. (C:\android-ndk-r15b).
INFO [2017-07-20 11:40:30Z]: ANDROID: sdk:   Key HKCU\SOFTWARE\Novell\Mono for Android\JavaSdkDirectory found:
    Path contains jarsigner.exe in \bin (C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_131).
INFO [2017-07-20 11:40:30Z]: ANDROID: Did not find Xamarin.Android
INFO [2017-07-20 11:40:30Z]: ANDROID: Found Android SDK. API levels: (none)
INFO [2017-07-20 11:40:30Z]: Xamarin.Android SDK not found, disabling Xamarin.Android addin
      Initializing Main Window
INFO [2017-07-20 11:40:30Z]: Creating DefaultWorkbench
INFO [2017-07-20 11:40:32Z]: Updating Welcome Page from 'https://software.xamarin.com/Service/News'.
INFO [2017-07-20 11:40:32Z]: Updating Prebuilt Apps from 'https://xamarin.com/PrebuiltApps.xml'.
INFO [2017-07-20 11:40:33Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.VersionControl.Subversion
INFO [2017-07-20 11:40:33Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.VersionControl.Subversion.Windows
INFO [2017-07-20 11:40:33Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.Xamarin.Ide.Windows
INFO [2017-07-20 11:40:34Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.UnitTesting.NUnit
node `classlib-gecko' is not defined on the documentation map
INFO [2017-07-20 11:40:34Z]: Prebuilt Apps image already up-to-date.
INFO [2017-07-20 11:40:34Z]: Prebuilt Apps image already up-to-date.
INFO [2017-07-20 11:40:34Z]: Prebuilt Apps image already up-to-date.
INFO [2017-07-20 11:40:34Z]: Prebuilt Apps image already up-to-date.
INFO [2017-07-20 11:40:34Z]: Welcome Page updated.
ERROR [2017-07-20 11:40:34Z]: An unhandled exception has occured. Terminating Xamarin Studio? False
System.TimeoutException: The operation has timed out.
   at System.IO.Pipes.NamedPipeClientStream.Connect(Int32 timeout)
   at Microsoft.ServiceHub.Utility.NamedPipeClientStreamExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<ConnectWithRetryAsync>b__0()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.ServiceHub.Utility.NamedPipeClientStreamExtensions.<ConnectWithRetryAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
node `classlib-taglib-sharp' is not defined on the documentation map
node `classlib-webkit' is not defined on the documentation map
INFO [2017-07-20 11:40:35Z]: Prebuilt Apps image already up-to-date.
INFO [2017-07-20 11:40:35Z]: Prebuilt Apps already up-to-date.
INFO [2017-07-20 11:40:35Z]: Prebuilt Apps updated.
INFO [2017-07-20 11:40:37Z]: Fetching vsid...
INFO [2017-07-20 11:40:37Z]: Refreshing entitlements...
INFO [2017-07-20 11:40:37Z]: Fetching entitlements...
INFO [2017-07-20 11:40:37Z]: Fetching auth token.
ERROR [2017-07-20 11:40:38Z]: Error fetching token
System.ArgumentException: The account is not supported by this provider. The configuration does not match.
   at Microsoft.Developer.IdentityService.Utilities.VerifyConfiguration(IAadConfiguration accountConfiguration, IAadConfiguration expectedConfiguration)
   at Microsoft.Developer.IdentityService.AccountProvider.AadAccountProviderClient.VerifyAccount(Account account)
   at Microsoft.Developer.IdentityService.AccountProvider.AadAccountProviderClient.<AcquireTokenAsync>d__40.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at Xamarin.Ide.Identity.MicrosoftIdentity.<GetTokenAsync>d__26.MoveNext()
ERROR [2017-07-20 11:40:38Z]: Error fetching rights
System.ArgumentException: The account is not supported by this provider. The configuration does not match.
   at Microsoft.Developer.IdentityService.Utilities.VerifyConfiguration(IAadConfiguration accountConfiguration, IAadConfiguration expectedConfiguration)
   at Microsoft.Developer.IdentityService.AccountProvider.AadAccountProviderClient.VerifyAccount(Account account)
   at Microsoft.Developer.IdentityService.AccountProvider.AadAccountProviderClient.<AcquireTokenAsync>d__40.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at Xamarin.Ide.Identity.MicrosoftIdentity.<GetTokenAsync>d__26.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Xamarin.Ide.Identity.MicrosoftIdentity.<GetTokenAsync>d__20.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Xamarin.Ide.Identity.VisualStudioOnlineLicensing.<FetchAndCacheEntitlementsAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
INFO [2017-07-20 11:41:01Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.ILAsmBinding
```

Anything else I can do?

Comment: Have you tried to run Android SDK Manager? Can it run normally?

Comment: @lowleetak Yes, I can run it normally.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the checkbox part by downloading Xamarin.Android standalone from my Xamarin subscription (downloads).

Although I have some other issues to fix (some things that have to do with the emulator) I can create Android projects now.

Uninstalling, re-installing VS 2017 and it's components did not solve the issue.